# Slicing strings in a column in pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a CSV that has a column of URLs and I'm trying to slice out some unnecessary characters leading and trailing characters. I'm using the following syntax:

```
df.['column_name'].str[3:10]
```

Unfortunately I get `TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable`.

Comment: Can you share the full traceback not just the last line?

Comment: it should be either `df['column_name'].str[3:10]` or `df.column_name.str[3:10]`, so you can simply remove the first dot-symbol

Answer (score 7):

`pandas` has a function to `slice` the entire column values, and is as follows:

```
df['column_name'].str.slice(start=3, stop=10)
```

Answer (score 6):

try this

```
df['new_column'] = df['text_column'].apply(lambda x: x[3:10])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:
df['new_col'] = df['column_name'].str[3:10]
all you have to do is deleting the dot between df and ['column_name']

Comment: The other users mentioned it already?